# tkz-graph doesn't respect color option to edge when Welsh or Normal style specified

Tags: tkz-graph

When I specify `\GraphInit`, the `\Edge` command doesn't respect any options.  In my case, I'd need to specify the color and line width.

In this example, I wanted to set one of the edges red and the other gray, and wanted thicker lines, but both edges stay black and thin.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
  \Vertices[unit=2]{circle}{1,2,3} 
  \AddVertexColor{gray!50}{1,2} \AddVertexColor{red!50}{3}

  \Edge[color=gray!50,lw=2pt](1)(2)
  \Edge[color=red!50,lw=2pt](1)(3)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I comment out `\GraphInit`, the options are respected but I won't get the 1,2,3 labels (plus, I do not want the labels in the vertices anyways).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LabelOut=true` option in `\Vertices[unit=2,LabelOut=true]{circle}{1,2,3}`.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tkz-graph}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  %\GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
  \Vertices[unit=2,LabelOut=true]{circle}{1,2,3} 
  \AddVertexColor{gray!50}{1,2} \AddVertexColor{red!50}{3}

  \Edge[color=gray!50,lw=2pt](1)(2)
  \Edge[color=red!50,lw=2pt](1)(3)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]